# Flask default pytests failing

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I was instructed to run the following commands and ensure all tests pass.

```
git clone https://github.com/pallets/flask
cd flask
python3 -m venv env
. env/bin/activate
pip install -e ".[dev]"
pip install pytest
python -m pytest
```

While all the tests should pass, currently 6 or 7 of the tests are failing. All of the failures are in "tests/test_instance_config.py". What can I do to ensure that all the tests will pass? Is the fact that these particular tests are failing significant? I am running Ubuntu 18 LTS.

```
=================================== FAILURES ===================================
____________________________ test_main_module_paths ____________________________

modules_tmpdir = local('/tmp/pytest-of-vedantroy/pytest-1/test_main_module_paths0/modules_tmpdir')
purge_module = <function purge_module.<locals>.inner at 0x7f2c7e4b6e18>

    def test_main_module_paths(modules_tmpdir, purge_module):
        app = modules_tmpdir.join('main_app.py')
        app.write('import flask\n\napp = flask.Flask("__main__")')
        purge_module('main_app')

>       from main_app import app
E       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main_app'

tests/test_instance_config.py:32: ModuleNotFoundError
________________________ test_uninstalled_module_paths _________________________

modules_tmpdir = local('/tmp/pytest-of-vedantroy/pytest-1/test_uninstalled_module_paths0/modules_tmpdir')
purge_module = <function purge_module.<locals>.inner at 0x7f2c7e45c378>

    def test_uninstalled_module_paths(modules_tmpdir, purge_module):
        app = modules_tmpdir.join('config_module_app.py').write(
            'import os\n'
            'import flask\n'
            'here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))\n'
            'app = flask.Flask(__name__)\n'
        )
        purge_module('config_module_app')

>       from config_module_app import app
E       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config_module_app'

tests/test_instance_config.py:46: ModuleNotFoundError
________________________ test_uninstalled_package_paths ________________________

modules_tmpdir = local('/tmp/pytest-of-vedantroy/pytest-1/test_uninstalled_package_paths0/modules_tmpdir')
purge_module = <function purge_module.<locals>.inner at 0x7f2c7e50abf8>

    def test_uninstalled_package_paths(modules_tmpdir, purge_module):
        app = modules_tmpdir.mkdir('config_package_app')
        init = app.join('__init__.py')
        init.write(
            'import os\n'
            'import flask\n'
            'here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))\n'
            'app = flask.Flask(__name__)\n'
        )
        purge_module('config_package_app')

>       from config_package_app import app
E       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config_package_app'

tests/test_instance_config.py:61: ModuleNotFoundError
______________________ test_installed_module_paths[True] _______________________

modules_tmpdir = local('/tmp/pytest-of-vedantroy/pytest-1/test_installed_module_paths_Tr0/modules_tmpdir')
modules_tmpdir_prefix = local('/tmp/pytest-of-vedantroy/pytest-1/test_installed_module_paths_Tr0/modules_tmpdir')
purge_module = <function purge_module.<locals>.inner at 0x7f2c7e45c378>
site_packages = local('/tmp/pytest-of-vedantroy/pytest-1/test_installed_module_paths_Tr0/modules_tmpdir/lib/python3.6/site-packages')
limit_loader = None

    def test_installed_module_paths(modules_tmpdir, modules_tmpdir_prefix,
                                    purge_module, site_packages, limit_loader):
        site_packages.join('site_app.py').write(
            'import flask\n'
            'app = flask.Flask(__name__)\n'
        )
        purge_module('site_app')

>       from site_app import app
E       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'site_app'

tests/test_instance_config.py:73: ModuleNotFoundError
______________________ test_installed_package_paths[True] ______________________

limit_loader = None
modules_tmpdir = local('/tmp/pytest-of-vedantroy/pytest-1/test_installed_package_paths_T0/modules_tmpdir')
modules_tmpdir_prefix = local('/tmp/pytest-of-vedantroy/pytest-1/test_installed_package_paths_T0/modules_tmpdir')
purge_module = <function purge_module.<locals>.inner at 0x7f2c7e48bd90>
monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x7f2c7e47d080>

    def test_installed_package_paths(limit_loader, modules_tmpdir,
                                     modules_tmpdir_prefix, purge_module,
                                     monkeypatch):
        installed_path = modules_tmpdir.mkdir('path')
        monkeypatch.syspath_prepend(installed_path)

        app = installed_path.mkdir('installed_package')
        init = app.join('__init__.py')
        init.write('import flask\napp = flask.Flask(__name__)')
        purge_module('installed_package')

>       from installed_package import app
E       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'installed_package'

tests/test_instance_config.py:89: ModuleNotFoundError
_____________________ test_installed_package_paths[False] ______________________

limit_loader = None
modules_tmpdir = local('/tmp/pytest-of-vedantroy/pytest-1/test_installed_package_paths_F0/modules_tmpdir')
modules_tmpdir_prefix = local('/tmp/pytest-of-vedantroy/pytest-1/test_installed_package_paths_F0/modules_tmpdir')
purge_module = <function purge_module.<locals>.inner at 0x7f2c7e48bd08>
monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x7f2c7e415828>

    def test_installed_package_paths(limit_loader, modules_tmpdir,
                                     modules_tmpdir_prefix, purge_module,
                                     monkeypatch):
        installed_path = modules_tmpdir.mkdir('path')
        monkeypatch.syspath_prepend(installed_path)

        app = installed_path.mkdir('installed_package')
        init = app.join('__init__.py')
        init.write('import flask\napp = flask.Flask(__name__)')
        purge_module('installed_package')

>       from installed_package import app
E       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'installed_package'

tests/test_instance_config.py:89: ModuleNotFoundError
_______________________ test_prefix_package_paths[True] ________________________

limit_loader = None
modules_tmpdir = local('/tmp/pytest-of-vedantroy/pytest-1/test_prefix_package_paths_True0/modules_tmpdir')
modules_tmpdir_prefix = local('/tmp/pytest-of-vedantroy/pytest-1/test_prefix_package_paths_True0/modules_tmpdir')
purge_module = <function purge_module.<locals>.inner at 0x7f2c7e47b488>
site_packages = local('/tmp/pytest-of-vedantroy/pytest-1/test_prefix_package_paths_True0/modules_tmpdir/lib/python3.6/site-packages')

    def test_prefix_package_paths(limit_loader, modules_tmpdir,
                                  modules_tmpdir_prefix, purge_module,
                                  site_packages):
        app = site_packages.mkdir('site_package')
        init = app.join('__init__.py')
        init.write('import flask\napp = flask.Flask(__name__)')
        purge_module('site_package')

>       import site_package
E       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'site_package'

tests/test_instance_config.py:102: ModuleNotFoundError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in pytest. The Github issue can be found here: https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/3151